Unhide and rename files in sub directories in Windows
Recently I had some sort of virus attack on Win 11. All the files such as as docx,pptx,pdf,mkv etc. have been hidden by the virus and dummy files of same name with size 0kb has been created.
Is there a Windows utility/commands to do all of the following in all folders & sub-folders recursively

Unhide the files, delete the 0kb version and remove extension "a21wvdtgi" from it?

All the files have 2 copies...
1 with original filename & 0KB Size (I need to delete this)
1 with original filename.pdf.a21wvdtgi extension which is hidden (I need to unhide & remove the extension)
What commands/utilities can perform all the above 3 tasks?
I could figure out the command to remove the extension as
forfiles /S /M *.a21wvdtgi /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname"


In Windows Explorer, there's a setting to view all files: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-hidden-files-and-folders-in-windows-97fbc472-c603-9d90-91d0-1166d1d9f4b5 If that does not show the file, then it's no longer in the file system.

All the files have 2 copies...
1 with original filename & 0KB Size (I need to delete this)
1 with original filename.pdf.a21wvdtgi  extension which is hidden (I need to unhide & remove the extension)
What commands/utilities can perform all the above 3 tasks?

You cannot use rename but move is in effect the same so use the following on a COPY test folder  of files. It "works for me".
forfiles /S /M *.a21wvdtgi /C "cmd /c attrib -h @file & move @file @fname"

You may need to run twice as one file was held locked on the first run so worked on the second run. That is about as "safe" as this method can be.

